# Keeping numbers in a range

Tags: c#, range

I am attempting to get some data validation done but I am really struggling with that. I have been using `If` statements and was hoping `If` (pun intended) someone could help me. I am very new to the whole thing and have a massive piece that needs to be done so far I have managed but this got me stumped. I really would like a push or something in the correct direction because it feels like I am rubbing my head against a piece of sandpaper

```
        int iNumber1;
        int iNumber2;


        Console.WriteLine("Please give me 2 number between -10 and +10 and ill add them together");
        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        iNumber1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        iNumber2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int iResult;
        //here i get the adding bit done
        iResult = iNumber1 + iNumber2;

        //bool bUserInput = false;



        //while (!bUserInput)
        //{
        //    string sInput = Console.ReadLine();

        //    if (iNumber1 < -10)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Your are out of range please stay between -10 and +10");
        //    }

        //    if (iNumber1 < 10)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Your are out of range please stay between -10 and +10 ");
        //    }

        //    if (iNumber2 < -10)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Your are out of range please stay between -10 and +10");
        //    }

        //    if (iNumber2 < 10)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Your are out of range please stay between -10 and +10");
        //    }

        //}


        if (iResult <= -10 || iResult >= 11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of range calculation is ignored");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That number is vaild and its {0}", iResult);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could we have  some more detail in the question. More detail about the problem itself. What are you trying to validate? I see you have given some code. What do you want it produce? Is it failing to do that, if so what is it producing instead?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I read your post, but I am not understanding as to what the actual question is here? Could you please clarify in better detail what the issue is and expected output so we can better assist you.

Comment: also since atm, you haven't specified a specific problem, I will give some generic advice. You should always validate user input as soon as possible. Here you capture input, operate on the input and then appear to validate different input

Comment: I dont see a proper question, Though you can use switch instead of IF. But using IF as you have done has no issue :)

Comment: Do you mean to be checking the range of `iResult` rather than `iNumber1` and `iNumber2`?

Comment: hi sorry i went to get some dinner. basically i am tryna get the user input to be between -10 and +10. This has proved to be rather annoying and i cant seem to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("Please give me 2 number between -10 and +10 and ill add them together\n");
        int iNumber1 = readNumber();
        int iNumber2 = readNumber();

        int iResult = iNumber1 + iNumber2;

        Console.WriteLine("The sum of {0} + {1} is {2}", iNumber1, iNumber2, iResult);
    }

    //you should use functions to avoid code repetition.
    //the function below reads the user input and tries to convert it into a number.
    //the validation rule is applied inside the loop.
    private static int readNumber()
    {
        bool bUserInput;
        int number;

        //below is a loop that runs at least once. the loop continues
        //iterating while the condition evaluates to true, otherwise it ends
        //and control goes to the statement immediately after it. 
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
            //Int32.TryParse receives as arguments a string to parse and
            //an integer as an output argument (you need the out keyword)
            //it returns true if it the string could be successfully converted
            //into an integer and false if it couldn't.
            bUserInput = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
            if (!bUserInput)//this will be true if the user input could not be converted
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input could not be converted into an integer number");
                //the continue statement is used inside a loop to skip the rest of it
                //and jump directly to the test condition
                continue;
            }
            if (number < -10 || number > 10)//the validation
            {
                //the error message
                Console.WriteLine("Your are out of range please stay between -10 and +10");
                //make sure we set the flag to false because in this case, 
                //Int32.TryParse has set it to true, but input is still invalid
                //by the validation rules.
                bUserInput = false;
            }
            else//the number is in range, set the flag to true
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good Job!\n");
                //set the flag to true, so the loop can end.
                bUserInput = true;
            }
        }while(!bUserInput);//while this evaluates to true, the loop continues.

        return number;
    }                   
}
```

Comment: @BurnedBurned I'm very glad I could help! Say, is anyone asking you to write your C# identifiers in Hungarian Notation? (start with i for integers, b for booleans, ch for characters, etc?) It is just out curiosity that I ask. Most people would advise that you should use the same name convention the Framework itself uses, but myself, I have experimented with several notations along my short years as a coder, even invented my own. Still, C# being so beautiful itself, I decided to adhere to the naming conventions of the good old FCL <3

Comment: yeah so this is for a school project. as i take the level 3 IT course it covers like 18 fields of study in the space of 2 years. coding is by far not my strongest suit due to the fact that i am horribily dyslexic. my teacher is a hard ass and makes sure that we use hungarian notation. its fine but i am going to struggle with the next subject which shall be object orentaied coding which i have no idea what that it is lol

Answer (score 0):

So you need a way to validate that a number is between -10 and +10 (inclusive). That should be easy:

```
bool isValid(int i)
{
    return (i >= -10) && (i <= 10);
}
```

now you need a function to see if *two* numbers are both valid:

```
bool areValid(int i1, int i2)
{
    return isValid(i1) && isValid(i2); 
}
```

Now just assume that input is not valid, and loop until it is:

```
bool isValid = false;
while(!isValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please give me 2 number between -10 and +10 and I'll add them together");
    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    iNumber1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    iNumber2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    isValid = areValid(iNumber1, iNumber2);
    if(!isValid)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Out of range calculation is ignored");
    }
}
```

Now you know you have two valid numbers and can continue with the rest of your program.

Comment: This is one of those rare situations where I may even use a `do ... while` loop since you always expect it to execute at least once.

Comment: pet peeve, but I find it much easier to visualize range checks if they are written as you would see it on a number line.. `return (-10 <= i) && (i <= 10);`  Now its quite clear that I'm looking for a number in-between -10 and +10.